# Can't Access System.Management Namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How to resolve this error?

System.Management is enable, but visual studio return error

Like this:

[image: VS 2010 Error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the reference for `System.Management` to the project.